# How to pass and iterate a list of objects from C# to NLua

Tags: c#, nlua

how should I pass and iterate a list of objects from C# to Lua?

My example with an array of `int`, when I use custom classes I get the same result:

```
state_ = new Lua();
state_.LoadCLRPackage();

var candidates = new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

state_["Candidates"] = candidates;

state_.DoString(script);

var b = state_["Candidates"] as int[];

return toRetrun;
```

Where the script is

```
-- Iterate each candidate
for k,v in ipairs(Candidates) do

    print(k, Candidates[k])

end
```

The output is:

```
1   1
2   2
3   3
4   4
5   5
```

It skips the first one and I get the exception: "Index was outside the bounds of the array."
What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C# Lists have the Count property. It can be used as upper-bound for iterations:

```
[...]
var candidates = new List<int> { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
[...]

[...]
-- Iterate each candidate
for candidateCount = 0, Candidates.Count - 1 do
[...]
```

Answer (score 1):

In Lua, indexing generally starts at index 1.  From [docs](https://www.lua.org/pil/11.1.html)

> it is customary in Lua to start arrays with index 1

Try something like this:

```
for i = 0, #Candidates do
     print(i, Candidates[i])
end
```

as I konw `ipairs()` only supports 1 indexing, so you'll have to define your own function or just use a regular for instead.

I'm not sure but also try

```
for k,v in ipairs(Candidates), Candidates, -1 do
  print(k, Candidates[k])
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but the # operator woks only on tables. The solution is easy tho, I forgot that C# Lists have the Count property and I can use it in Lua. So your answer is correct if you put Candidates.Count instead of #Candidates and I use a List instead of an Array in C#

Comment: Glad to have been of help. Also please see an update

Comment: I tested the code in the update. It starts correctly from the first element but I still get an index out of bound exception at the end of the list